# How can a material be conductive and transparent at the same time?

Tags: visible-light, electronic-band-theory

[Transparent conducting films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparent_conducting_film) for example.

On one hand, the band structure of transparent materials must have a large enough HOMO-LUMO separation.

On the other hand, conducting (metallic) materials do not have a high (if any) HOMO-LUMO separation.

Comment: It's right there in the article you cite: "Transparent materials possess bandgaps with energies corresponding to wavelengths which are shorter than the visible range of 380 nm to 750 nm". Did you not read that? So what's your question, then?

Comment: @CuriousOne, that's a [pretty big bandgap](http://www.tf.uni-kiel.de/matwis/amat/semi_en/kap_5/illustr/bandgap_misfit.gif) and materials with such bandgap are not even considered conductors... so what am I missing here?

Comment: There is no inherent law that forbids bandgaps this large (at least I am not aware of such a mechanism) and if the material conducts electricity, then it is, by definition, a conductor. Are you possibly having a semantic problem with that?

Comment: @CuriousOne, the carrier concentration due thermal exictation decays exponentially with the band gap. What I don't understand is how such a big band gap affords enough carrier concentration to have conductivities of $10^3$ S/cm.

Comment: Oh, I see. Highly conductive semiconductors with high non-thermal conductivity have large dopant concentrations. It's the dopants that cause sufficiently large carrier concentrations but it's the bandgap that prevents photons from exciting the electrons from jumping across the bandgap. In case of oxides it seems that reducing the oxygen content creates an intrinsic dopant concentration.

Answer (score 1):

The usual conduction mechanism for intrinsic semiconductors is that thermal excitation of electrons from the valence to conduction band creates mobile electrons in the conduction band and mobile holes in the valence band. Both of these move in response to an applied voltage and therefore conduct electricity.

You're quite correct that if the band gap is greater than optical energies the thermal excitation of electrons into the conduction band is negligably small and such materials can't conduct electricity by this mechanism. But other conduction mechanisms exist. If you look at [the theory section of the article you cite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparent_conducting_film#Theory) it says:

> Charge carriers in these oxides arise from three fundamental sources: interstitial metal ion impurities, oxygen vacancies, and doping ions.

For example, if you start with indium tin oxide and remove an oxygen atom you are left with a vacancy in the crystal lattice with two electrons localised at this vacancy. This creates a gap state just below the conduction band, so in effect we get an N type semiconductor that conducts electricity like N-type doped silicon.

Comment: How can one tell the relative position of gap states due modifications, such as the oxygen vacancy you mentioned to be "just below the conduction band"?

Comment: @Sparkler: I'm not an expert in this area, but as a general rule it's exceediingly difficult to predict in advance exactly where a gap state will be, though of course it's a lot easier to post-rationalise its position :-)